# Similar to Ajax Update panel in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, updatepanel

Need to refresh Page Automatically, is there event / Command in Jquery Similar to Ajax Update panel... like the one below, coz, Jquery validation's is not working with UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" updateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

Comment: Have you tried just using jQuery load on the panel div? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: its not like Ajax update panel..... My Criteria is on .Net I am using drop down list box, selecting Country its State must be displayed, if I use Ajax Update panel page refreshed is smooth & other data like Password etc., is not Lost. if I use "meta" tags while page is refreshed value in Password field is Lost. is there Any Command in Jquery i have similar like Ajax Update Panel. Coz, If i Use Ajax Update Panel validation in Jquery are not displayed. or let me know how to stop "Submiting a form" is validation fails using JQuery, I am using Jquery With Update panel.